# What Windows OS will my machine have when I restore it to factory settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, system-restore

Long story short I have to restore PC.

My PC was upgraded to Windows 10 free of charge but natively had Windows 8 installed.

I made a system repair disk as suggested by Microsoft and now I need to use it. However, I wonder, if I restore the PC to factory settings, the OS will probably be Windows 8. But I would like to keep Windows 10, how can I do this?

PS: I do not save restore points and shadow copies since they fill too much space on disk.

Comment: Just use the Refresh feature built into Windows 10 instead of using the factory restoration accomplishes what you want.  The factory reset will install Windows 8 since that's the image contained within the partition which was not updated when you upgraded to Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

When you put the PC to factory reset from Windows 10, it will reset to the first point after the upgrade in Windows 10, alternatively you can search for Reset PC in the start menu, and clean everything and perform a windows 10 reinstall, optionally keeping your files and programs located on the C: drive. (other drives will not be harmed in any way)

Also, if the BIOS has a factory reset option, it is very likely it will now reset to Windows 10 too.